# Convert null in json_encode to empty strings?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am having trouble trying to convert null values to empty strings with the results of my `json_encode`:

```
    if ($uresult->num_rows >0) {


 while($urow = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {


 $rresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM allid WHERE postid='$oldid' AND spaceid='$newid'");
 $lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult);
 $tem = $lrow['postid'];

 $ujson = json_encode($tem);
 echo $ujson;
 }

} else {
}
```

Here is the result of the `$ujson`:

```
"10"nullnullnullnull"25"
```

I looked up answers and I got this answer:

```
array_walk($tem,function(&$item){$item=strval($item);});
```

Doing this caused me to get this error:

```
Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
```

Is this the correct way to convert a null to an empty string, if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it already says `string given`, it means `$tem` is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like what I've said in the comments, it says `$tem` is a `string`. `array_walk` needs an array for it to work properly.

Anyway, if you intend `null` values to turn into empty string `''`, just `array_map` with `strval` the array you got, so that it applies `strval` each element in the array. Then finally, encode it.

Here's the general idea:

```
$lrow = array_map('strval', $lrow);
```

Looking more in depth, you should put all items inside a container first, and then finally encode them. Don't encode each batch. Regarding the `$tem`'s, then you wouldn't need `array_walk`, just a ternary operator:

```
$post_ids = array();
if ($uresult->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($urow = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM allid WHERE postid='$oldid' AND spaceid='$newid'");
        $lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult);
        $tem = !is_null($lrow['postid']) ? $lrow['postid'] : '';
        $post_ids[] = $tem;
    }
}

echo json_encode($post_ids);
```

Sidenote: As much as possible, avoid using a `while` loop, and inside it another query under it (imagine having a thousand rows; it will query a thousand times too). Use `JOIN` statements instead.

Comment: Ok I did this and got this error: `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array `

Comment: @LaneyWilliams you apply it into an array, anyways, just check out the edit, it should show you in the right direction

Comment: Good answer, I would've done it the same way with `array_map()`

Comment: @Darren looking at the question as a whole, i think the OP doesn't need an `array_walk` or `array_map` at all.

Comment: @Ghost Just did haha, it's early here and I haven't had my coffee yet. Your edit sums up nicely ;-)

Comment: @Darren coffee works wonders, my brain never work without it.  :D

Answer (score 4):

Try this way -

```
//Array
$array = ["id" => 1, "name" => "Rohit Suthar", "city" => null, "mobile" => null];

//Convert null value to empty string 
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$item){$item=strval($item);});

echo json_encode($array);
```